# Can someone please explain me what exactly is Node in this below piece of code in java?

Tags: java

```
class Node
 {    
 Node l, r;
 int val;
 int h;


 public Node()
 {
     l = null;
     r = null;
     val = 0;
     h = 0;
 }
```

What are we doing in the line? :

Node l,r;

This only a part of a program that I did not include here. 
Thanks.

Comment: `Node` is a class.  It sounds like an introductory tutorial on Java would be very helpful here...

Comment: Node with left, right, value, and h variables suggests that this is for a binary tree implementation that holds integers.  When you understand Java better you can make this a generic class so your binary tree can hold anything.

Comment: Most likely this is a node of a binary tree where l,r represent the left and right child node of the Node.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell you *exactly* what it is, because how would we know.

But, we can make educated guesses, based on the badly named fields<sup>1</sup>:

- `l` should really be named `left`
- `r` should really be named `right`
- `val` should really be named `value`

That would make the class appear to be a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) node.

Don't know what `h` is, but it could be a `height` value, representing the height of the sub-tree.

<sup>1</sup> *[Badly named fields](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):*

> Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the casual observer the intent of its use. **One-character variable names should be avoided**, except for temporary "throwaway" variables.

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is the name of the class that you're defining.

`Node l, r;` defines two variables of the `Node` type inside of each instance of `Node` but does not initialize them (each node has the possibility of containing two nodes, the left and right).

Comment: Two instances of the Node class (not two variables) on each new instantiated Node object.

Comment: @acornagl - There are no instnaces of the `Node` class declared in the code above. Each of the private instance variables are set to `null` in the constructor.